# Socket io server freezing(it seems) after certain amount of time?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

My code is too long to post in here, but basically I use socket.io server to pull data from database and refresh in the client every 1 second.
Like this:

```
function updateTimer(){
    //db->query
    io.sockets.emit('updated data', data);
}
setInterval(updateTimer, 1000);
```

After a certain amount of time, the server just stops emitting data. I use a chat on the website as well and it stops too. But in the server console nothing is shown, no errors or any outputs, just "listening on port 3000..." stays on the screen all the time.

I thought it could be the loop maybe but I think there's no other way of refreshing data every 1 second, am I right?
If someone can help me and needs the full code please open a discussion and I'll paste it somewhere.

EDIT for the function code:

```
function checkRoulleteTime() {
            try {
                pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
                    connection.query('SELECT * FROM `roullete` WHERE status=\'active\'', function(err, rows) {
                        if (err) {
                            console.log(err);
                            return;
                        }
                        if (rows.length == 0) return;
                        var time = rows[0].time - (Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000));
                        if (time <= 1) {
                            connection.query('UPDATE `roullete` SET `status`=\'closed\' WHERE `id`=\'' + rows[0].id + '\'', function(error, fields) {
                                if (error) throw error;
                            });
                            setTimeout(roll, 1000);
                            setTimeout(function(){
                                io.sockets.emit('add hist');
                            }, 10500);
                            setTimeout(updatePoints, 12000);
                            setTimeout(newRound, 12500);
                        }
                        var contagem = Object.keys(clients).length;

                        io.sockets.emit('login count', contagem);
                        io.sockets.emit('roullete time', time);
                        connection.query('SELECT SUM(points) as points FROM `roullete_bets` WHERE `round`=\'' + rows[0].id + '\' AND `color`=\'black\'',function(error2, rows2){
                            if (error2) throw error2;
                            connection.query('SELECT SUM(points) as points FROM `roullete_bets` WHERE `round`=\'' + rows[0].id + '\' AND `color`=\'green\'',function(error4, rows4){
                                if (error4) throw error4;
                                connection.query('SELECT SUM(points) as points FROM `roullete_bets` WHERE `round`=\'' + rows[0].id + '\' AND `color`=\'red\'',function(error3, rows3){
                                    if (error3) throw error3;
                                    var onBlack = rows2[0].points;
                                    var onRed = rows3[0].points;
                                    var onGreen = rows4[0].points;
                                    io.sockets.emit('calculations', {"time": time, "black" : onBlack, "red" : onRed, "green" : onGreen});
                                });
                            });
                        });
                    });

                    connection.release();
                });
            } catch(e) {
                console.log('error here:'+e);
            }
            setTimeout(checkRoulleteTime, 1000);
        }
        setTimeout(checkRoulleteTime, 1000);
```

Alright, that's my code.

Comment: What you have posted is not enough information to go on.  It could be any one of lots of different causes.  You will probably need to add various forms of logging to your code to learn more about what is and isn't executing.  For example, you might want to add a `console.log()` in `updateTimer()` so you can see if that function is even being called.  If it is, then you know to look in the socket.io code.  If it's not being called, then you have a large macro issue in your server that made it stop running.  Debugging like this is an iterative process.  Instrument, learn, narrow problem, repeat.

Comment: You can also look at the network trace (either server end or client end) to see if there is any data flowing on the webSocket connection.  And, of course, this could be a client-side issue too where the data is being sent to the client, but something is wrong in the client that prevents it from doing anything visible with the data.

Comment: The function is being called. Everything is working fine when I start the server, after certain amount of time(couldn't keep track of how much time or even if it's a fixed amount) it just stops. Will I have to console log everything to see if I find the issue?

Comment: This is a classic debugging problem.  You need to gather more information to narrow the problem down and lead you to where you then need to gather more information until eventually you've found the root cause.  You can gather more information by either inserting log statements in various places or using tools such as network traces (that let you see what networking is happening).  This is an iterative process.  Gather more information, decide what that tells you and where you should then gather some more information, repeat over and over until you've isolated the problem.

Comment: Alright, that will demand a lot of patience but I see no other way. Just 1 thing: Is there any chance of the issue being the mysql query process taking more than 1 second and then breaking the loop or something? Cause sometimes the mysql is slow due to high traffic. Maybe is there a way of forcing the loop to hold until the whole process is done(if it takes more than 1 sec) before looping again?

Comment: If your db is slow, that will just make the timers be slow, not stop anything.  My guess is that you have a programming error in your db query and you are running out of some resource related to your database so your db query fails every time after a little while and because it's inside a `setInterval()` you don't see the exception that is happening.  If you include that specific code, we can likely help give you some ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you have some sort of programming error in your database query that, after a little while exhausts some resources so your database query starts failing every time, throwing an exception or just returning an error and thus you don't ever send any data because of the error.  Because the code is inside the `setInterval()` callback, any exception is not logged for you.

We could probably help you further if you included your actual database code, but you can start to debug it yourself by putting an exception handler around it like this:

```
function updateTimer(){
    try {
        //db->query
        io.sockets.emit('updated data', data);
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}
setInterval(updateTimer, 1000);
```

And, if your DB query is async (which I'm assuming it is), you will need to have explicit error handling and an exception at each callback level (since exceptions don't propagate up async callbacks).

If your database may get slow, then it might be safer to change your recurring code to work like this:

```
function updateTimer(){
    try {
        //db->query
        io.sockets.emit('updated data', data);
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
    // schedule next updateTimer() call when this one has finished
    setTimeout(updateTimer, 1000);

}
// schedule first updateTimer() call
setTimeout(updateTimer, 1000);
```

---

You have LOTS of places in your code where you are leaking a pooled connection and lots of places where you are not logging an error.  My guess is that you are running out of pooled connections, getting an error over and over that you don't log.

Here's a version of your code that attempts to clean things up so all errors are logged and no pooled connections are leaked.  Personally, I would write this code using promises which makes robust error handling and reporting a ton easier.  But, here's a modified version of your code:

```
function checkRoulleteTime() {
    try {
        pool.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("Failed on pool.getConnection()", err);
                return;
            }
            connection.query('SELECT * FROM `roullete` WHERE status=\'active\'', function (err, rows) {
                if (err) {
                    connection.release();
                    console.log(err);
                    return;
                }
                if (rows.length == 0) {
                    connection.release();
                    return;
                }
                var time = rows[0].time - (Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000));
                if (time <= 1) {
                    connection.query('UPDATE `roullete` SET `status`=\'closed\' WHERE `id`=\'' + rows[0].id + '\'', function (error, fields) {
                        if (error) {
                            console.log(error);
                            connection.release();
                            return;
                        }
                    });
                    setTimeout(roll, 1000);
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        io.sockets.emit('add hist');
                    }, 10500);
                    setTimeout(updatePoints, 12000);
                    setTimeout(newRound, 12500);
                }
                var contagem = Object.keys(clients).length;
                io.sockets.emit('login count', contagem);
                io.sockets.emit('roullete time', time);
                connection.query('SELECT SUM(points) as points FROM `roullete_bets` WHERE `round`=\'' + rows[0].id + '\' AND `color`=\'black\'', function (error2, rows2) {
                    if (error2) {
                        console.log(error2);
                        connection.release();
                        return;
                    }
                    connection.query('SELECT SUM(points) as points FROM `roullete_bets` WHERE `round`=\'' + rows[0].id + '\' AND `color`=\'green\', function (error4, rows4) {
                        if (error4) {
                            console.log(error4);
                            connection.release();
                            return;
                        }
                        connection.query('SELECT SUM(points) as points FROM `roullete_bets` WHERE `round`=\'' + rows[0].id + '\' AND `color`=\'red\'', function (error3, rows3) {
                            connection.release();
                            if (error3) {
                                console.log(error3);
                                return;
                            }
                            var onBlack = rows2[0].points;
                            var onRed = rows3[0].points;
                            var onGreen = rows4[0].points;
                            io.sockets.emit('calculations', {
                                "time": time,
                                "black": onBlack,
                                "red": onRed,
                                "green": onGreen
                            });
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    } catch (e) {
        console.log('error here:' + e);
    }
    setTimeout(checkRoulleteTime, 1000);
}
setTimeout(checkRoulleteTime, 1000);
```

---

And to give you an idea how much simpler it can be to do error handling and chaining of sequential or dependent async functions, here's your function rewritten using promises.  I have no idea if this runs without error since I have no way of testing it, but it should give you an idea how much cleaner programming with promises can be:

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
pool = Promise.promisifyAll(pool);

function logErr(err) {
    console.log(err);
}

function checkRoulleteTime() {
    pool.getConnectionAsync().then(function(connection) {
        var query = Promise.promisify(connection.query, {context: connection});
        return query('SELECT * FROM `roullete` WHERE status=\'active\'').then(function(rows) {
            if (rows.length !== 0) {
                var time = rows[0].time - (Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000));
                if (time <= 1) {
                    query('UPDATE `roullete` SET `status`=\'closed\' WHERE `id`=\'' + rows[0].id + '\'').catch(logErr);
                    setTimeout(roll, 1000);
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        io.sockets.emit('add hist');
                    }, 10500);
                    setTimeout(updatePoints, 12000);
                    setTimeout(newRound, 12500);
                }
                var contagem = Object.keys(clients).length;
                io.sockets.emit('login count', contagem);
                io.sockets.emit('roullete time', time);
                function doQuery(color) {
                    return query('SELECT SUM(points) as points FROM `roullete_bets` WHERE `round`=\'' + rows[0].id + '\' AND `color`=\'' + color + '\'');
                }
                return Promise.all([doQuery('black'), doQuery('green'), doQuery('red')]).then(function(results) {
                    io.sockets.emit('calculations', {
                        "time": time,
                        "black": results[0][0].points,
                        "green": results[1][0].points,
                        "red": results[2][0].points
                    });
                });

            }
        }).catch(logErr).finally(function() {
            connection.release();
            setTimeout(checkRoulleteTime, 1000);
        });

    }, function(err) {
        console.log("Err getting connection: ", err);
    });
}
```

Comment: My code is kinda long, can we open a discussion and I paste it somewhere? This way You can see whats going on

Comment: @MarcielFonseca - The place to put code that is required to understand a question here on stack overflow is to paste it into your question and format it as code.  That's how you do things here.  There are no length limits I'm aware of.

Comment: Many people are looking for those codes, I was offered like $1k for the codes and I just don't want to sell it :/... It's not that I'm selfish, but I'm sure if someone else makes a site like mine they will do it better and I'll get no traffic anymore. That's all, I wanted to show it only for You

Comment: @MarcielFonseca - This site doesn't work that way.  The question here and all resources required to answer it must be public.  If you want us here to help you with the DB code you have to share it.  Otherwise if you want to keep the code private (which is your right), we've given you a pretty solid idea where to look (at all your DB error handling) and if you make absolutely sure that all possible error paths in your DB code are logging their error, you will probably find the problem.

Comment: Ok, I understand. I'll take a look and try to catch the errors. Thank You

Comment: I hope You understand I'm not being selfish or something. If you saw my site You'd understand that I can't leak the code. Thank You anyway

Comment: @MarcielFonseca - It's your choice - I'm just explaining how this site works.

Comment: One last question, if I do like in the second example(recalling setInterval I believe that's what you meant) it will overwrite the current interval? Won't I have problems like calling twice/second the same function?

Comment: @MarcielFonseca - my second example uses `setTimeout()`, not `setInterval()`.  It schedules the next `updateTimer()` call for 1 second after the previous one has finished it's work, thus guaranteeing that the next iteration starts 1 second after the prior one finished, no matter how long the dB operation took.

Comment: Oh, how dumb am I xD... Thank You!

Comment: I tried the second option and it didn't work, like before it doesn't show any messages and just stops working, does not catch an error and I dont know what to do

Comment: @MarcielFonseca - If you catch all possible exceptions and log all possible code paths, you will be able to figure out what's going on.  Not much else we can do here since you don't want to post your DB code.

Comment: If you mean my mysql query code, I sure can post it here. I thought you wanted all my server code. Is it just the queries?

Comment: @MarcielFonseca - Just the code that gets executed inside the `updateTimer()` function.

Comment: It definitely doesn't fit on a comment or answer, should I paste.bin it?

Comment: @MarcielFonseca - There's no limit I'm aware of to code in a question.  The system will limit the height of the box and make it scrollable to keep it from taking over the screen. The idea here is that ANY code that is needed to solve the question MUST be pasted into the question. An external reference link can be provided, but not as the only source of the relevant code. This is because stack overflow is meant to be a lasting reference and external links tend to stop working or get modified rendering the original question not very useful any more. For that reason, code must be IN the question.

Comment: @MarcielFonseca - Multiline code should never be put in a comment because it simply won't be readable.

Comment: @MarcielFonseca - Which specific node.js database library are you using?

Comment: @MarcielFonseca - ALL your throw statements in that code are silent.  They don't log.  They won't be caught anywhere.  You should at least log an error to see if the code goes that path.  A throw in an async callback does not propagate to a higher level.  It just goes back in the DB infrastructure and gets lost.

Comment: But in case the error event is triggered, won't it just "crash" the server and show the failure? I'm using mysql module, I guess that's the database library(isn't it?)

Comment: @MarcielFonseca - No.  It probably won't crash the server.  It will probably just be ignored because it's inside an async callback.  That's different than an unhandled exception elsewhere.  Try it yourself sometime.  Just do a `throw` inside a `setTimeout()` callback.

Comment: Ok, so You suggest I log all errors inside those mysql.queries right? About the database library, did I say ti right? I use mysql module to connect to mysql

Comment: @MarcielFonseca - See the modified code I added to the end of my question.  You had lots of code paths where you l could eak a pooled database connection.  You were probably then running out so all database operations were failing once the pool was exhausted.

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to mention, it's not only this function that stops working, all the server(chat and bets) stops.

Comment: I'm using your code, lets hope this function is what's causing the server to stop... I'll let You know, thank You!

Comment: @MarcielFonseca - Any other code where you use the database probably needs similar fixes.

Comment: Alright, I'll try that. I keep You updated if any news. You're really saving me man, thanks

Comment: @MarcielFonseca - I realized my code has a few typos.  It is not logging the right `errorx` variable (too much copy/paste).  You will need to make sure each `console.log()` is logging the right error variable.  I just edited the code in my answer to correct that.

Comment: Plus, under this line `connection.query('SELECT SUM(points) as points FROM roullete_bets WHERE round=\'' + rows[0].id + '\' AND color=\'red\'', function (error3, rows3) {` I believe You didn't mean to release the connection outside the error scope, right? I moved it.

Comment: @MarcielFonseca - That's the last query.  You must release the connection there whether error or not.  Where I put it was done on purpose.

Comment: @MarcielFonseca - I also notice that you're trying to run this every second.  But, you're doing 4-5 database operations in each run.  That could easily take more than 1 second to run which would mean you'd end up getting things backed up and multiple calls to `checkRouletteTime()` would be operating at the same time.  This could also exhaust your connection pool and overload your database.  You should probably not start the timer for the next operation until you're done with the current operation. Since you have lots of possible exit paths, you will have to put a `setTimeout()` lots of places.

Comment: Strangely, after using your code, the problem is occurring more often, less than 1 minute after I start the server. Same as always, no messages or anything.

Comment: @MarcielFonseca - Put a `console.log()` in every piece of the code path so you can track every step of the execution and see which is the last one that gets hit.  This is how you have to debug an intermittent problem, particularly with async code.  You log the heck out of it until the log tells you where it gets stuck.

Comment: Yah, I see no way other than that. Just noticed now that this last problem occurred when I made the same changes in the other functions. Just one question, makes any difference if I put like that `function (param1, param2)` or like that  `function(param1, param2)` (the second one with no spaces between the function name and the params). Cause in the sublime editor it shows with a color if I use the space, and no color if I put no spaces

Comment: @MarcielFonseca - I added a new implementation to my answer that shows what your code could look like if you implemented it with promises.  Of major note here is how much simpler the error handling, logging and connection release are.

Comment: If i paste it directly over my original code should it work right away or Do I have to do any changes? I'm not familiar at all with promisses

Comment: @MarcielFonseca - If I didn't make any mistakes, it is supposed to be a drop-in replacement.

Comment: What about the connection setup(hostname, db, user, pass)? Where to place it in your code? xD i'm sorry but I'm really not familiar with promisses

Comment: @MarcielFonseca - My code covers exactly the same `checkRoulleteTime()` function that you put in your question.  You did not disclose any connection setup code so I did not do anything with that.  You must have had it somewhere else.  This should be a drop-in replacement for `checkRoulleteTime()`, nothing else.

Comment: I asked because the pool variable was already declared, here is it in my code: var pool = mysql.createPool({
    agent: false,
    connectionLimit: 100,
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'xxx',
    password: 'xxxx',
    database: 'xxxx',
    debug: false
});

Comment: @MarcielFonseca - I'm just modifying your existing `pool` object to promisify the methods on it.  This should not affect your other code that uses the `pool` object or sets it up.  If I had all your code, I'd probably do it a little bit differently, but based on what you shared, this should work and not mess anything else up.

Comment: Ok, I'll try that. Thank You very much

Comment: @MarcielFonseca - I showed the Promise version to you as an example that might hopefully inspire you to learn promises.  This is fairly advanced code and it might not be perfectly written since I have no way of testing it.  If you have issues with it, it may be more than you know how to fully understand and fix yourself in your first use of promises.  I hope you learn from it, but keep in mind you might want to crawl, walk, run with promises in that order and this is already a fast jog.

Comment: { [Error: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'black' in 'where clause']
  cause:
   { [Error: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'black' in 'where clause']
     code: 'ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR',
     errno: 1054,
     sqlState: '42S22',
     index: 0 },
  isOperational: true,
  code: 'ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR',
  errno: 1054,
  sqlState: '42S22',
  index: 0 }

Plus, I added an extra ")" closing the function, not sure if its right but it was missing somewhere check in the next comment

Comment: @MarcielFonseca - I fixed the `Promise.all()` code in my answer.  It was missing a close `)` and the arguments need to be in an array.  I also probably fixed the `'ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR'` because I wasn't forming the query quite the same as you.  It apparently needs quotes around the `black` which my answer now does.

Comment: I just realized that and was able to fix it. A even deleted my comments, didn't realize you had answered it already. Now, the only thing I have a doubt is about the setTimeout X setInterval in this function. Since it displays the time left for the roulette to spin I need it to be triggered every 1 second, the setTimeout way is making the timer go weird. Should I reverse it to setInterval or maybe it could bring me some problem?

Comment: @MarcielFonseca - Sorry, but I don't understand your timer issue.  I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish or which code is trying to do that.

Comment: This function displays the time left until the roulette spins(among others things), io.sockets.emit('roullete time', time); is sending the time left in seconds to the client. So I need it to send with a fixed interval of 1 second

Comment: @MarcielFonseca - Updating the client on a regular timer should probably be done completely separate from this code on an interval timer.  Though a client can count time all by itself, so maybe the client could be started counting by the server and then it can just run its own counter and the server only updates the client if something changes.

Comment: I thought about that but it just makes me confused about how to tell the client what round to count and if the server is stopped and many other things. Will I have problem if I just put this function inside an interval?